# An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement when using sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have This code

```
update T1
set T1.Column1= (Select  SUM(T2.Column2))
FROM T2
WHERE T2.Column2 LIKE '%Building%';
```

But end up with this error "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement" when using SUM function.

What I really wanted with my query is that I have 2 Tables, T1 and T2, I like to update T1 which has value of 100 (with LIKE '%Building% function),  using sum it must be come up with the total  value from T2 Column2 which is 200 (with LIKE '%Building% function). Thank you for the help

```
T1
Column1  
100    

T2
Column1            Column2
Land               100
Building           50
Building           100
Machinery          50
Building           50
```

Comment: You close your subquery early, as you have the second right parenthesis (`)`) after the `SUM` expression. It should be `SELECT SUM(T2.Column2) ... LIKE '%Building%');`...

Comment: Thank you @Larnu didnt expect that fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Would you please check this query below:

```
create table #T1
(
Column1 int
)

create table #T2
(
Column1  varchar(500),         
Column2 int
)

insert into #T1
select  100

insert into #T2
select 'Land', 100
union all
select 'Building', 50
union all
select 'Building',100
union all
select 'Machinery', 50
union all
select 'Building', 50   


update #T1 
set Column1 = (Select  SUM(Column2) FROM #T2 WHERE Column1 LIKE '%Building%')

select * from #T1
```